# How to locate an element using selenium that does not have id/name or any other unique identifier?

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-rc, selenium-webdriver

There are two fields in the page: Username and Password(Highlighted in the below code with **). Need to enter data into it using selenium. However, both the objects have same identifier elements except tabIndex. Please help me as to How to identify the elements(Please refer html).

Please note: The below code worked for me but user will not be able to see the data that is input in the GUI. I want the data to be seen on the UI.

Thanks,
Mike

```
@FindBy(name="cams_cb_username")
private WebElement emailId;

@FindBy(name="cams_cb_password")
private WebElement password;   
((JavascriptExecutor)DriverFactory.getDriver()).executeScript("arguments[0].setAttribute('value',arguments[1]);", emailId, "username");
((JavascriptExecutor)DriverFactory.getDriver()).executeScript("arguments[0].setAttribute('value',arguments[1]);", password, "pwd");
```

Here is the HTML.

```
<form action="/vito-mma/activateLogin.do" method="post" name="loginForm">
<input type="hidden" value="vitocom" name="cams_security_domain">
<input type="hidden" value="/vito-mma/showPlans.do" name="cams_original_url">
<input type="hidden" value="http" name="cams_login_config">
<input type="hidden" value="" name="cams_cb_partner">
<fieldset class="mma-signin">
<div class="clearfix">

<**input class="bigtext e-hint" type="text" value="" name="e_hint_dummy_input" size="25" autocomplete="off" tabindex="1" style="display: inline;"**>

<input class="bigtext e-hint" type="text" title="Email address" value="" tabindex="1" size="25" name="cams_cb_username" style="display: none; background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);" autocomplete="off">
</div>
<div class="clearfix">

<**input class="bigtext e-hint" type="text" value="" name="e_hint_dummy_input" size="25" autocomplete="off" tabindex="2"**>

<input class="bigtext e-hint" type="password" title="Password" value="" tabindex="2" size="25" name="cams_cb_password" style="display: none; background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);" autocomplete="off">
</div>
</fieldset>
<div class="indent">
</form>
```

**Note:**
Tried with Xpath: Did not work.
Recorded with IDE for username, (name="cams_cb_username"). Used this  - Did not work either.

Comment: General question - Is your login form publicly available, so we can try it and offer better solution?

Comment: Unfortynately No. I work for a client and it will be a violation of the contract if i am sharing any info here. Thanks for asking.

Comment: Have you tried with CSS-selector?

Comment: Not really sure how to sure css selector in this case. Could you please help me? I have very less knowledge on using CSS locators

Comment: By the way, you have four inputs here, and you are selecting the two which are not correct, accordingly to your description.

Comment: @loan I tried with this: @FindBy(xpath="\\input[@tabindex='1']") - It didn't work... Then I tried with the absolute xpath (//form/fieldset/div[1]/input[1]) - Even this didn't work. However, When I use Javascript executor with @FindBy(name="cams_cb_username") - IT WORKS. But the data being entered in the fields are not seen. It is directly set into the variable. I am expecting it to be seen as well.  (Js executor is what I have mentioned in the original post)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could customize the xpath to use the `tabindex` attribute and the `name` attribute :

```
@FindBy(xpath="\\input[@name='cams_cb_username' and @tabindex='1']")
private WebElement emailId;

@FindBy(xpath="\\input[@name='cams_cb_password' and @tabindex='2']")
private WebElement password;
```

Or alternatively, you could use something like this :

```
WebElement username = wait.until(presenceOfElementLocated(By.xpath("\\input[@name='cams_cb_username' and @tabindex='1']")));
WebElement password = driver.findElement(By.xpath("\\input[@name='cams_cb_password' and @tabindex='2']"));
username.clear();
username.sendKeys(username);
password.clear();
password.sendKeys(password);
password.submit();
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks for the response. As I already told in the first post, I did use xpath, It doesn't work!! This line does not throw any errorthough, it is successfully executed but in the GUI - nothing is entered into those fields.

Comment: Tried exactly what you have mentioned. I get following error:     Element is not currently visible and so may not be interacted with

Comment: @Mike That's because the two inputs have a `display:none` style set. Are you trying to set the inputs with the `name` attribute set to `cams_cb_username` and `cams_cb_username` or the ones marked with the **?

Comment: :I tried with this: @FindBy(xpath="\\input[@tabindex='1']") - It didn't work... Then I tried with the absolute xpath (//form/fieldset/div[1]/input[1]) - Even this didn't work. However, When I use Javascript executor with @FindBy(name="cams_cb_username") - IT WORKS. But the data being entered in the fields are not seen. It is directly set into the variable. I am expecting it to be seen as well.

Comment: @Mike You have two input entries with tabindex=1. You need to specify another attribute to identify a single one. Try using the name as well. If you are trying to select the input marked with ** in your example, you could use `\\input[@name='e_hint_dummy_input' and @tabindex='2']`

Comment: @Mike Then input with the name cams_cb_username isn't displayed (`style='display:none'`). You can't see data being entered.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/19534/discussion-between-mike-and-axxa-osiris)

Answer (score 2):

For those types of fields, its good to use Xpath. Because I am also Xpath newbie, there is way, how I do this:

- Install [Selenium IDE](http://seleniumhq.org/projects/ide/) and click (and type) the field you want to type in
- In the selenium IDE you will see the locator which the IDE used. You can change it further

The xpath will look like `//input/div` or something like that. I dont know exactly, here I am really newbie

In code you then use

```
@FindBy(xpath="/the/xpath/provided/by/selenium_ide")
```

**EDIT**

See this image
[image]

Here I created simple test task with Selenium IDE - open your question, click to search box and type "search"

In the last command, the IDE proposed me the most obvious solution for locator. But I can change that.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. Have added a note in the question. Had tried this already and it did not work for me.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, on your post you marked different two inputs than the ones you have in the description (`@FindBy(name="cams_cb_username")` & `@FindBy(name="cams_cb_password")`.

However, for what you've marked with `**`, the corresponding CSS selectors are :

1. First one : `.clearfix:nth-child(1) input[name="e_hint_dummy_input"]`
2. Second one : `.clearfix:nth-child(2) input[name="e_hint_dummy_input"]`

Comment: @loan. Thank you. You are right. May be I should have re-phrased the question. The Xpaths and the css suggested by in these post are all correct but when i run it - It is not working... But when I use the Javascript executor and do this:     ((JavascriptExecutor)DriverFactory.getDriver()).executeScript("arguments[0].setAttribute('value',arguments[1]);", emailId, "username");
    ((JavascriptExecutor)DriverFactory.getDriver()).executeScript("arguments[0].setAttribute('value',arguments[1]);", password, "pwd"); IT works. but user is not able to see the data being entered on the GUI object

Comment: By the way, why do you set "value" to "username" and "pwd"?

Comment: @loan: I tried  ur suggestions - It didn't work.   "username" and "pwd" are the credentials to login

Comment: Well, try to do it as AxxA Osiris says in the second approach : driver.findElement(By.cssSelector(..)).sendkeys("pwd/username");

Answer (score 0):

You can directly use names for locating elements : like 
1.For usrname use : selenium.type("cams_cb_username","your UN");
2.For password use: selenium.type("cams_cb_password","your PWD");
Or u can use like:
For username :   //input[@name='cams_cb_username'];
For PWD  :  //input[@name='cams_cb_password'];

These should work.